# PayPal IPN Failure: 500 Error. Is my handler bad?

Tags: paypal, handler, paypal-ipn

We all know the PayPal documentation stinks to high heaven, so please, a little latitude if i overlooked/misunderstood something critical.

my IPN handler seems to return a 500 Error to the sandbox tester.

here's my handler.  pretty straightforward: just write the $_REQUEST array to a file:

```
<?php
//  PayPal Instant Payment Notification Handler
session_start();

        $pp_logFile = "./PayPal_log.log";
        $fileHandler = fopen($pp_logFile, 'a') or die('Cannot open file');
        $feedback = null;
        foreach($_REQUEST as $key => $val)
        {
            $_SESSION[$key] = mysql_prep($val);
                //  load the feedback variable with the values to write to the logfile
            $feedback .= $key . ' => ' . $value . ' \n'; 
        }

        fwrite($fileHandler, $feedback);
        fclose($fileHandler);
?>
```

don't know what i'm missing.  seems pretty simple since all i want to do is see what the hell that IPN is sending so i can build my script accordingly... eventually, i'm trying to grab the txn_id for use in a 'success' page as well as see if i can pass a custom variable through it.

Comment: Wasn't my downvote, but a little focus on grammar, punctuation, and capitalization will go a long ways to properly communicating your question.

Answer (score 0):

[According to the sample](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPN_PHP_41.txt) it connects back to PayPal. Perhaps the IPN expects you to do the same as part of the notification?

Comment: as i understand it, the handler get's *called* by the IPN.  the handler does nothing itself until then.  it's not an active document, but a reactive one... again, as i understand it.  WR!

Comment: @WhiteRau That's how I understand it to. But perhaps part of the reaction is phoning back to PayPal. And as a side note, I expect HTTP 500 would be on your server's side, so you might want to check error logs or enable header logging temporarily and see if PHP is raising some kind of error.

Comment: i'll contact my ISP and find out what the heck is going on.  thank you.  WR!

Comment: Yeah, your script is returning a 500. That's got nothing to do with PayPal (except for PayPal being the party who sends the POST data to it). Talk to your host and see if you can get the Apache error logs to find out why it's returning a 500.